# How to restrict/customize the Resource Group Region in ARM templates

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

When we deploy a Custom template in Azure then a few parameters like Resource Group and Region are automatically popped up in the Azure portal (see the attached screenshot). I want to know how can we customize or restrict the list of regions using ARM templates.

[image: ARM Template Deployment Screenshot]

**Edit**

[image: Modified ARM Template]

[image: New parameter Region is added rather than re-using the existing one]

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Is that you want to know how to implement azure resource can only be deployed to certain regions?

Comment: The attached screenshot is for the case when I deployed the empty ARM template. The parameter Region is automatically added which is having all possible values. I want to control this list like if I need to have only "uksouth" and "eastus" in the Region dropdown. Since this parameter region is not controlled by the ARM template then how can I control it? Is there a way to do that?

On a side note, I am aware about how to deploy a Azure resource in a particular region.

Comment: You can define the region value in the parameter :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-parameters

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't help me. It adds up a new parameter in the GUI rather than controlling the existing one which gets added automatically. I have edited the post to include the sample template and the output GUI. Could you please take a look and let me know if I did something different than what you had suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "region" dropdown is for the resourceGroup's location - it's required when creating a new one, disabled when using an existing one.  For a custom template, you cannot customize or remove that control unless you provide your own ui definition file.

That said, there's also nothing that requires you to use the value from that control in your deployment.  If you want to use that value you'd reference it using resourceGroup().location in your template.  That would allow you to remove the "duplicate" but also requires that the resources are deployed to the same region as the resourceGroup.

For your own "region" control, you can use the allowedValues property on the parameter in the template and that will restrict the items in the list to what you provide - that's the link that Jim provided in the comment above.

If you supply your own ui definition file there are more things you can do to restrict the list, but requires you to write a bit more code.  This would be the starting point:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-overview

The docs talk about managedApplications, but the ui is a generic construct that you can use for template deployments, here's a generic example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/100-marketplace-sample

[edits post comment]

If you want to leverage the "built-in" region control you can customize the list of locations that appear there by setting the config in the createUiDefintion.json file.  More on that here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-overview#config

Comment: Thanks @bmoore-msft. Thanks for the confirmation. I was looking if it is feasible to customize Resource Group Location so that I can deploy resources in the same region as of Resource Group but in limited regions as per my need. This prevents the needed of separate parameters but as you said it is not possible. Thanks

As you mentioned, I have been using a different parameter to limit the regions in which my Azure resources can be deployed.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer above, I think you can do what you want with your own CUID, lmk if something isn't clear.